# Why can't I click on this menu?

Tags: php, html, input

Clicking will not work. Checked source, list is populated with PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your padding on the div on the right is overlaying the left div containing your select:

```
.right {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 220px; // <- This line
    position: absolute;
    top: 58px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, adding a negative z-index worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter - No problem. :) If this answers your question, make sure and hit the checkmark next to the answer below the vote talley. :)

Comment: @Jared Need to wait 3 mins ;)

Comment: @Peter - Ok, no problem.

Comment: Wow, I've never met a mind reader before.

Comment: @Tim - It's a gift. 8) There was a link in the original incarnation of the question, so my secrets are exposed.

Comment: @tim That code isn't supposed to be public, just needed quick help. I'm going to add the source so people can get the gist of the issue.